# Retrieve values fom database using JDBC Template in hashmap

Tags: jdbc, hashmap, jdbctemplate

i am using JDBC template for getting data from database in Spring MVC.
my query is:

```
SELECT count(A.MEETING_ID),ITEM_TBL.REG_EMAIL FROM ITEM_TBL,MEETINGS_TBL WHERE ITEM_TBL.MEETING_ID=MEETINGS_TBL.MEETING_ID 
GROUP BY ITEM_TBL.REG_EMAIL
```

this is returning rows like:

```
11 nishant@gmail.com
12 abhilasha@yahoo.com
13 shiwani@in.com
```

i want to store these value into Hash MAP. Can you please help how can i do this using JDBC TEMPLATE?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need [ResultExtractor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html).

You can achieve that using below code.

```
String sql = "SELECT count(A.MEETING_ID),ITEM_TBL.REG_EMAIL FROM ITEM_TBL,MEETINGS_TBL WHERE        ITEM_TBL.MEETING_ID=MEETINGS_TBL.MEETING_ID 
        GROUP BY ITEM_TBL.REG_EMAIL";

ResultExtractor mapExtractor = new ResultSetExtractor() {
   public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      Map<String, String> mapOfKeys = new HashMap<String, String>();
      while (rs.next()) {
        String key = rs.getString("MEETING_ID");
        String obj = rs.getString("REG_EMAIL");
        /* set the business object from the resultset */
        mapOfKeys.put(key, obj);
      }
      return mapOfKeys;
   }
};

Map map = (HashMap) jdbcTemplate.query(sql.toString(), mapExtractor);
```